# Installing full text feature for Sql Server (compatibility issue)

Tags: sql-server

I have Ms Sql Server Express 2005 currently installed. I need to install the "Sql Server Express with Advanced Services" from Microsoft, found here (in order to enable full-text search feature):

http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPCTAV2/enus/default.aspx

**Problem is: the "Express with advanced services" component is from 2012, and my Ms Sql Server is from 2005. Are they compatible? Do I risk messing up the Sql Server installation if I run this service?** 
I'm very short of time and I don't want to mess up my installation and have to reinstall. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Installing Express with Advanced Services will install a new instance of SQL Server. Compatibility won't matter because only the new Express instance will have Full-Text capability and your existing SQL Server 2005 instance won't be able to use it. What you probably want to do is install Full-Text for the instance you already have installed - you can do this through Add/Remove Programs for the existing SQL Server 2005 instance (assuming you still have the install media for SQL Server 2005), which will call up the Installation Center where you can choose to add features to an existing instance.